# How to stop bots from crawling my AJAX-based URL's?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, url, web-crawler, bots

I've got several pages on my ASP.NET MVC 3 website (not that the technology matters here), where i render out certain URL's in a `<script>` tag on the page, so that my JavaScript (stored in an external file) can perform AJAX calls to the server.

Something like this:

```
<html>
   ...
   <body>
      ...
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function() {
            myapp.paths.someUrl = '/blah/foo'; // not hardcoded in reality, but N/A here
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now on the server-side, most of these URL's are protected with attributes stating that:

a) They can only be accessed by AJAX (e.g XmlHttpRequest)

b) They can only be accessed by HTTP POST (as it returns JSON - security)

The problem is, *for some reason*, bots are crawling these URL's, and trying to do HTTP GET's on them, resulting in 404's.

I was under the impression that bots shouldn't try and crawl javascript. So how are they getting a hold of these URL's?

Is there any way i can prevent them from doing this?

I can't really move these URL variables to an external file, because as the comment in the code above suggests, i render the URL's out with server-code (must be done on the actual page).

I've basically been added routing to my website to HTTP 410 (Gone) these URL's (when it's not a AJAX POST). Which is really annoying, because it's adding another route to my already convuluted route table.

Any tips/suggestions?

Comment: Are there any `<a>` tags pointing to them, anywhere? Which bots are hitting them?

Comment: @RPM1984: just out of curiosity, have you compiled stats on the number of hits by user agent?  From this, what sorts of bots are you most plagued by?

Comment: I think googlebot has some limited ability to crawl javascript, so that could be a problem. Googlebot respects robots.txt however so you could just set that up to prevent it crawling them.

Comment: You are now officially introduced to the new Googlebot feature that executes javascript in websites

Comment: While there seems to be a lot of hate on Google here, I'm still not convinced OP is being plagued by them, especially since OP never mentioned anything specific, and especially since bots (other than the big google/yahoo/ect) in general usually bypass any restrictions you put in place.  OP: can you provide more details on exactly which bots you think are trying to overwhelm you here?

Comment: all types of bots. google, yahoo, slurp. no, there are no a tags pointing to them. it's just a javascript variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disallow URL by the prefix in the robots.txt

Comment: what do you mean "by the prefix"? can you expand a little?

Comment: i.e. 

"Disallow /blah"
which will prevent crawlers to look all urls which start with /blah (e.g. /blah/foo

You can be more specific and disallow as many entries as you need.

Comment: hmm not really feasible. i have around 20 ajax'ified urls, with different paths/formats. so unless i move them all to a certain url path, i would need 20 robots.txt entries.

Comment: There could be no miracles. You either need to reorganize AJAX url you don't want to expose to search engines or add 20 entries to robots.txt (btw, not that many entries).

Comment: You should add that you can use wildcards such as `*`. This means you can have all your ajax urls starting with `/bleh/` and add `bleh/*` in your `robots.txt`.